# Python command to wait for shell (ubuntu csh) finishing action / return code

Tags: python, linux, shell, ubuntu

I'm running a Python command + API to access ECMWF (European Centre for Medium range Weather Forecast) data server (called MARS) and download some files (weather data). I launch the Python code with shell (I'm using csh) doing `./python_script.py` in the shell

It runs fine if I download a single file (year 1999 with `range(1999, 2000)` in my script, instead of `range(1998, 2000)` in the below failing example of Python script). Now I want to download many of them and thus make a loop over years.

My problem is that it seems the Python script doesn't wait for the shell command(s) / API to be finished and continue on the next year. It results in errors. The file are produced but with zero size.

I'd like to know if I can specify the Python script to wait to find some key words in the shell window before proceeding to the next for/loop step.

I know I'm using some specific API in that case and could probably find another API-specific solution to do so, but it seems easier to me to identify some print out in the shell.

It could be for instance "Transfer rate" which seems to appear in the shell window only when the job has been done, see the log (last successful lines) I've saved from shell (with `./python_script.py >& log_file.log`.

MY PYTHON CODE IS:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
for year in range(1998, 2000):
from ecmwfapi import ECMWFDataServer
server = ECMWFDataServer()
server.retrieve({
    "class": "e2",
    "dataset": "era20c",
    "date": '%d-07-01/%d-07-02' % (year,year),
    "domain": "g",
    "area" : "12/-72/-67/22",
    "grid" : "1.0/1.0",
    "expver": "1",
    "param": "214.140/233.140",
    "step": "3/9/15/21",
    "format" : "netcdf",
    "stream": "wave",
    "target": '/home/nicolas/hycom/hycom_data/ECMWF/ERA20C/forecast/%d/test_era20c_wave_set1.nc' % (year),
    "time": "06",
    "type": "fc",
})
```

MY LOG LAST LINES FOR ONE FILE DOWNLOADING ONLY (SUCCESSFUL):

```
2016-02-13 16:00:21 Request is complete
2016-02-13 16:00:21 Transfering 239.441 Kbytes into /home/nicolas/hycom/hycom_data/ECMWF/ERA20C/forecast/1999/test_era20c_wave_set1.nc
2016-02-13 16:00:21 From http://stream.ecmwf.int/data/atls04/data/data01/scratch/_grib2netcdf-atls04-95e2cf679cd58ee9b4db4dd119a05a8d-JLUk0w.nc
2016-02-13 16:00:28 Transfer rate 32.6278 Kbytes/s
```

Comment: Are you sure there is data for all years? Does it work if you try out with `range(1998,1999)`?

Comment: Hi Arton, thanks for the quick answer, yes there is data, and it works find with range(1998,1999)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to import in the loop, also it might be indentaiton problem. If your script is as you provided it, then the `retrieve` is not in the loop. Indentation in python matters s lot.

Try rewriting the script this way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from ecmwfapi import ECMWFDataServer
server = ECMWFDataServer()
for year in range(1998, 2000):
    server.retrieve({
        "class": "e2",
        "dataset": "era20c",
        "date": '%d-07-01/%d-07-02' % (year,year),
        "domain": "g",
        "area" : "12/-72/-67/22",
        "grid" : "1.0/1.0",
        "expver": "1",
        "param": "214.140/233.140",
        "step": "3/9/15/21",
        "format" : "netcdf",
        "stream": "wave",
        "target": '/home/nicolas/hycom/hycom_data/ECMWF/ERA20C/forecast/%d/test_era20c_wave_set1.nc' % (year),
        "time": "06",
        "type": "fc",
    })
```

Comment: Hi Nikita, Thanks for the answer, impressive the community quickness and help... 
I had some indentation (I copied wrong) but also some space between the for line and the first (indented) command line. I found strange actually that no ending command where to be specified... which is explained by the indentation sensitivity. I changed it and it works!!!
You rock, thanks again

Comment: @Nicolas, glad that it helped! You might want to accept the answer as a solution, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.